# Why would you want a dot at the start of a fqdn in a CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: url, cors

I've recently seen a URL listed in a CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header where the fqdn portion starts with a dot (eg. 'http://.example.com').

I'm struggling to think of a good reason for this, though I believe it is a valid URL.  I suspect a mistake somewhere but I don't know, there might be some application I'm unaware of.

Anyone able to enlighten me?

Comment: If you type it in a browser, it removes the leading dot.  And a link with it in, just tries to find the urls locally.

Comment: `without-a-dot-this-domain-would-match-the-filter-but-might-be-malicious-example.com`

Comment: I would have thought you'd need a asterisk at the start to get that behaviour @Virsacer; do you have a link to documentation confirming your suggestion?